# Modify Variable within Method with Service

Tags: php, oop

I want to know the right way to handle this scenario: modify a variable within a method with a service.  I know you could just do:

```
$input = $this->modify($input)
```

But that doesn't feel like the correct OOP way of handling the situation.  Please see the inline comments.

```
class myClass {

    public function __construct(Service $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function work($input)
    {
        // $input = SOMETHING
        $this->service->modify($input);
        // $input = SOMETHING MODIFIED
        Entity::create($input);
    }
```

}

Comment: *"But that doesn't feel like the correct OOP way of handling the situation"* is baloney. It would be perfectly fine to do so. If it's more logical depending on context is another story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by passing in the input as reference:

```
public function modify(&$input) {
//                     ^ See what I did there?
```

A better approach would be to return the modified input, and assign it again:

```
$input = $this->service->modify($input);
```

Don't start messing with references until you know **exactly** what you're doing.

Comment: I was experimenting with other design patterns and if input was a private variable in the service then I could modify($input) then getInput().  Does that make good sense?

Comment: @drewschmaltz: No, if input was a private on another class, you won't be able to modify it by reference. You'd need to get a copy using `getInput()` then return the result, and assign in the original class.

Comment: I ended up creating a getter method in the Service class but Madara Uchiha answered my real question which ended up being "how to pass by reference".  I'm not sure this question is going to help anyone, but I think we can consider it answered.